# Total glibc malloc() bytes

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory

How do I get the total number of bytes malloc()'d in a program (Assume I am running with glibc)? 
I do not want to see how much memory the program is taking, I want to see how much memory I allocated. Below is an example program where these numbers would be very different.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<void *> p;
    printf("Allocating...\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024 * 10; ++i) {
        p.push_back(malloc(1024));
        memset(*p.rbegin(), 0, 1024);
    }
    printf("Press return to continue...\n");
    getchar();
    printf("Freeing all but last...\n");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < p.size() - 1; ++i)
        free(p[i]);
    printf("Press return to continue...\n");
    getchar();

    // UNTIL THIS FREE, TOP WOULD SHOW THIS PROGRAM TAKES 16G,
    // BUT THE TOTAL MALLOC() SIZE IS MUCH LESS.

    printf("Freeing last...\n");
    free(*p.rbegin()); 
    printf("Press return to continue...\n");
    getchar();
}
```

I know this can be implemented with LD_PRELOAD or by having my own `malloc` and `free` functions, but is there a simpler way to get the `malloc()` total?

Comment: You'll have to calculate that yourself.  Perhaps with a macro that calls your own extended `malloc` function: `#define MALLOC my_malloc`.

Comment: Nice, er, "C++" HERE.

Comment: `tcmalloc`, from Google, has extensive statistics accessible, so once you have `LD_PRELOAD`ed it, you can use its specific functions to query its state.

Comment: (even if you're interested in libc, your code is C++ (especially from the use of the `vector` template))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The various language standards say:

There is no platform independent way of getting this information. Different implementations of malloc may provide this information, but it would  be in a non-standard way.

### Glibc offers:

- You could use the [`__malloc_hook`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html) feature to write up a hook that counts how much memory has been allocated.
- There's also [`mallinfo()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Statistics-of-Malloc.html#Statistics-of-Malloc), which should provide some information about what memory has been allocated.

Comment: Edited to mark that I am interested in libc. Still waiting to see if there is a simpler facility than using the hook. If not, will mark you as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Make a global variable and your own `malloc()` function

```
static size_t count;

void *malloc_ex(size_t n)
{
    count+=n;
    return malloc(n);
}
```

Then any time you can now how many bytes were allocated by looking inside the `count`variable.

Global variables are initialized to 0 by the compiler so it will be ok.
And please do not `#undef` `malloc` and re `#define` it as `malloc_ex()` this will be Undefined Behavior.

Comment: An additional free_ex() function should be also defined in order to decrement the allocated memory amount, which would also need to have control of the memory amount allocated with every call to malloc_ex.

Comment: I recommend `#define MALLOC malloc_ex` and `#define FREE free_ex`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: I think you need to write a motivation for why you recommend those macros.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy So the calls are consistent and easily extensible.  Sorry Professor. :-D

Comment: @Claudix, how would you keep track of the memory amount allocated? You say, "would also need to have control of the memory amount allocated with every call to malloc_ex.", but don't indicate a mechanism. BTW, I think your answer was better than this one. You just needed to pad your structure.

Comment: @TRKemp I deleted my answer because it was downvoted due to possible incompatibilities with the actual malloc implementation. I've undeleted the answer in order to let you discuss it.

Answer (score 1):

You should define two functions and also allocate extra space to keep track of the memory allocated by each call to the custom allocator functions.

```
//Space to store the size of an allocation
struct _room {
    size_t sz;  //Chunk size     
    char padding[16-(sizeof(size_t) % 16)]; //Force 16-byte alignment   
}

//A global variable to keep track of the total amount of memory allocated (except the extra space of storing chunk sizes
static size_t TOTAL = 0;


//Custom allocator
void *mymalloc(size_t sz) {
    //Allocate memory plus room for storing the chunk size. We'll need it later in 
    //myfree() to appropriately decrement TOTAL.
    struct _room *r = (struct _room *) malloc(sz + sizeof(struct _room));
    r->sz = sz;
    TOTAL += sz; //keep track of user allocated memory
    return (void *) (r+1); //Pointer to usable memory
}

void myfree(void *m) {
    //Point to the register with chunk size, given the memory pointer returned my mymalloc()
    struct _room *r = ((struct _room *) m) - 1;
    TOTAL -= r->sz; //Update total
    free((void*)r); //Free all memory: room + user memory
}
```

Comment: You run the risk of breaking the native alignment for malloc if you do this, e.g. on some platforms malloc is 16 byte aligned and code for that platform may rely on this alignment.

Comment: I know there are compiler directives in order to force structure alignment. How could be my code be fixed to achieve a 16-byte alignment?

Comment: There are various ways to handle this, but one method would be to pad `struct _room` to maintain the minimum alignment for the platform, e.g. for Mac OS X, where `malloc` is always at least 16 byte aligned, you could pad `struct _room` to make it 16 bytes in size.

Comment: OK, I've added pad to fill the 16-byte space required.

Comment: OK - that works for platforms with 16 byte alignment, which is probably the maximum that you will encounter currently. Ideally you'd make this adapt to alignment of the target platform, but I can't think of an easy to  do this just now.

Comment: @Claudix You need to set `r->sz` in `mymalloc()`.